# SharePoint 2013 using SharePoint Design 2010 workflow email breaking

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, workflow, designer-workflow

I've built very simple workflows based on a task list - on current item, if THIS is selected, send email to thisperson@email.com

The email body has several fields to display from the list.

The workflow will work fine for a bit, then just stop working.

When I go check the workflow, sometimes the email addresses are gone, sometimes the fields are no longer connected.

This happens when there have been no changes made to the workflow or the list other than adding an item to the list.

I've rebuilt the entire workflow from scratch several times.

Has anyone seen this before? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What’s the version of SharePoint Designer?

If you use SharePoint Designer 2010, I suggest you using SharePoint Designer 2013 version with SharePoint 2013.

If you use SharePoint 2010 workflow platform in SharePoint Designer 2013, troubleshot this issue below:

1. Clear the SharePoint Designer Cache [though this link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33469.how-to-clear-your-sharepoint-designer-20102013-cache.aspx)
2. Use other lists in the same site and another site, and use other email addresses to check again.